# group points in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, visualization

What I want to do is each polygone with number of points should be represented with a different color inside gnuplot

(data file looks like this)
`

```
6.185000    8.219000
6.566000    4.724000
1.392000    7.538000
6.185000    8.219000

8.455000    5.243000
1.776000    5.401000
1.515000    5.455000
8.455000    5.243000
```

`

And my script.gpl
`

```
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb '#dd181f' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 5 pointsize 1.5

set datafile separator "\t"

plot 'path\data.txt' index 0 with linespoints linestyle 1, \
     ''                   index 1 with linespoints linestyle 2
```

`

the script above works only of each polygone has **2 or less points** any number above and It shows me '**warning: Skipping data file with no valid points**'

Comment: Please always provide data as text, not as image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** you need 2 blank lines to separate subblocks which you want to address via `index`.

Your script a bit shortened, and using spaces instead of `TAB` as separator because I don't know how to post and format `TABs` in StackOverflow.

**Script:**

```
### addressing subblocks via index
reset session

$Data <<EOD
6.185000    8.219000
6.566000    4.724000
1.392000    7.538000
6.185000    8.219000


8.455000    5.243000
1.776000    5.401000
1.515000    5.455000
8.455000    5.243000
EOD

set style line 1 lc rgb 0x0060ad lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5
set style line 2 lc rgb 0xdd181f lw 2 pt 5 ps 1.5

set datafile separator whitespace

plot $Data u 1:2 index 0 w lp ls 1, \
     ''    u 1:2 index 1 w lp ls 2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: TSM for your time ,it worked!